# Mysql Update JSON Int Array Column

Tags: mysql, json

I got a table with below configurations

> Table: jsontesttable Column : ArrayCol  of type Medium Text  Sample
> value:  [123,45,67,85,78]

I use the below query to select List of IDS except one of the selected IDs

```
/*query to select list of IDs from the column and remove unwanted columns from the selection */

SELECT hm.Id FROM  jsontesttable tbl,
JSON_TABLE(ArrayCol, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm
WHERE hm.Id NOT IN (67,85)
```

I used below query to get the JSON array back but its treating as string at present

```
/*Convert the IDs back to a JSON int array like [123,45,78] */

SELECT JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(hm.Id SEPARATOR ',')) AS IDs FROM   jsontesttable tbl,
JSON_TABLE(ArrayCol, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm
WHERE hm.Id NOT IN (67,85)
```

But its generating rows like this only Not really needed to have " in the beggining and end

> //["123,45,78,88,9,3,53,6"] //["83,97"]

```
/*Update the ArrayCol , column as the new array without the removed values! 
Perform this updation only if ArrayCol contains one of these IDs in thisc ase it is 67 & 85 
*/
```

Can i write direct UPDATE query to modify the column without the IDs that needs to be removed like

```
[123,45,67,85,78]  => [123,45,78]   //2 IDs changed
[67,222,14] => [222,14] //Just 1 ID is changed 
[83,85,97] => [83,97]   //Just 1 ID is changed
[21,12,17,19]  =>  [21,12,17,19]  //No change
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT ArrayCol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
         FROM jsontesttable )
SELECT rn, JSON_ARRAYAGG(hm.Id) AS IDs 
FROM   cte
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(ArrayCol, '$[*]' columns (Id int path '$')) AS hm
WHERE hm.Id NOT IN (67,85)
GROUP BY rn
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce067ef12d9ed0d0ef1866e0a32d2a40